# Parasite axis appearing at two positions and overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib

using this example as guidance:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html
I tried to make a plot with multiple axes using twiny in stead of twinx.
However, one of the axes - par2 appears both in top and bottom location, overlapping par1 on top. What am I doing wrong?

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

par1 = host.twiny()
par2 = host.twiny()

new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["bottom"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="bottom",
                                    axes=par2,
                                    offset=(0, -40))
par2.axis["bottom"].toggle(all=True)

host.set_xlim(0, 2)
host.set_ylim(0, 2)

host.set_ylabel("Distance")
host.set_xlabel("Density")
par1.set_xlabel("Temperature")
par2.set_xlabel("Velocity")

p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], label="Density")
p2, = par1.plot([0, 3, 2], [0, 1, 2], label="Temperature")
p3, = par2.plot([50, 30, 15], [0, 1, 2], label="Velocity")

par1.set_xlim(0, 4)
par2.set_xlim(1, 65)

host.legend()

host.axis["bottom"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.axis["top"].label.set_color(p2.get_color())
par2.axis["bottom"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try to recreate this without using outside code that other users might not have (such as us_std) - this will help you get more answers.

Comment: I changed the code. Now it is the original code with my attempt to change the axes. That should fix that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the Matplotlib website example and your code is that you're adding the parasite axes adjacent to the "normal" axis location (i.e., the bottom) whereas the example is adding them adjacent to the "abnormal" or twinned axis.

The `par2 = host.twiny()` call sets the `par2` top axis to be visible and this isn't undone by the `new_fixed_axis()` call, so you need to switch this off using,

```
par2.axis["top"].toggle(all=False)
```

Note that, weirdly, you can also achieve this by replacing the top axis rather than the bottom one:

```
par2.axis["top"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="bottom",
                                  axes=par2,
                                  offset=(0, -40))
```

But that's probably a whole world of confusion waiting to happen.